# Python interpreter: New indented line without executing

Tags: python-3.x

I am just working through this tutorial:

http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

and I'm using the pyhton3-interpreter in Ubuntu 13.10 Terminal:

I tried to type this program:

```
 >>> # Fibonacci series:
 ... # the sum of two elements defines the next
 ... a, b = 0, 1
 >>> while b < 10:
 ...     print(b)
 ...     a, b = b, a+b
 ...
```

but the program always executes prematurely after the line "print(b)" and pressing ENTER. How do I get in the new line without executing?

Error message:

```
 >>> a=0
 >>> b=1
 >>> while (b < 10):
 ... print(b)
   File "<stdin>", line 2
     print(b)
         ^
 IndentationError: expected an indented block
 >>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you have to respect the indentation, even when in the interactive shell. So after you enter the `while` line, when the interpreter shell shows this:

```
>>> while (b < 10):
...
```

you have to insert some spaces to indent the `print` line, and the same number of spaces for all of the following lines within the same block (everything in the loop), just like you see it in the example program you are trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry about that. I finally found my mistake. I thought the three dots at the beginning ... already stood for the indentation. This works now:

... [TAB] print(b)

I got so used to regular python files that I forgot about this for the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the indentation of `print(b)`

```
while (b < 10):
    print(b)
```